# Git, ignored files appear in every branch

Tags: git, github

I have a repo `test-repo`, it contains two branches `master` and `dev`. Any files / directories that are in the `master` branch's `.gitignore` files appear locally in both branches when I `git checkout` to them, I assume this is normal behaviour as those files aren't being tracked by Git so they're just in the `test-repo` directory no matter what. I don't want this to happen. My ideal setup is like below:

When I `git checkout master` the local file / directory structure should be like so:

```
test-repo/
  .gitignore (this file just contains `should-be-ignored.md`)
  should-be-ignored.md
  should-only-show-in-master.md
```

When I `git checkout dev` the local file / directory structure should be like so:

```
test-repo/
  should-only-show-in-dev.md
```

If anyone has any idea on how to achieve this setup I'd really appreciate it.

The real-world version: I'm working on GitHub, when you add a branch of `gh-pages` it acts as free static web hosting essentially. I have a repo which contains my front-end web build boilerplate, the `master` branch contains all the code and the `gh-pages` branch would include some examples of what the code does etc. When I'm working on the boilerplate locally I run Grunt (a task runner) which to run properly needs the command `npm install` which installs any dependencies, this creates a directory of `node_modules` in the root of repo, I don't want this to show on the remote repo so I put that directory in the `.gitignore` file. So in my `dev` branch (locally) this directory still shows up, what if I wanted separate Grunt tasks for the files in the `dev` branch? This would mean I'd need another `node_modules` directory in that branch, which can't be done since the one from the `master` branch is always in that local directory no matter what. Do you see my problem now?

Comment: When you tell Git to ignore a file, it ignores it. The file `should-be-ignored.md` doesn't exist in *either* branch; it is completely outside of the system and thus Git does not touch it. Could you explain a little bit more about your goal (i.e., *why* do you want to do this)? I suspect that there may be a better solution for whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Chris: Just updated my answer with this "The real-world version"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the additional context you have provided regarding gh-pages (thought I am bit confused about master and dev branches coming in to the picture):

The gh-pages branch is essentially a separate repo and serves a different purpose (usually documentation.)

What I generally do is to not keep checking out between by code branch and gh-pages branch. I just clone the repo two times and have one for normal development, and the other for gh-pages stuff. Keeps it simple, and the two are treated as two repos, as they should be.

Comment: I upvoted this since it's a good solution, but are you sure that the `gh-pages` branch is technically a separate repository? I believe it's *logically* a separate repository, but not technically.

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, technically might be a wrong word. Changed to `essentially`

Comment: @manojlds: Yeah sorry, I tried simplifying it but probably made the question more complicated. So I'd have two local directories set up (`boilerplate` and `boilerplate-docs`) both with the same remote repo. When I want to push changes from the `boilerplate` directory I'd `git push origin master` and when I want to push changes from the `boilerplate-docs` directory I'd `git push origin gh-pages`. Is this the workflow you're talking about?

Comment: @Tom - Yes. That is what I do for many of my projects on Github too. I have my code, and my documentation/project available at the same time. (I usually create a parent folder to hold the two repos too.)

Comment: It's worth noting that this is the same workflow that is provided by GitHub for wikis; they *are* technically separate repositories. I'm not sure why GitHub Pages content is treated differently from GitHub wiki content.

Answer (score -2):

Start with backing up the relevant files and deleting them from your `test-repo` directory.

On branch `master`, add the file `should-only-show-in-master.md` and commit. Switch to branch `dev` delete the `should-only-show-in-master.md`, add the `should-only-show-in-dev.md` and commit.

Add the file `should-be-ignored.md` to your `.gitignore` in the `master` branch.

Comment: This won't prevent `should-be-ignored.md` from existing when `dev` is checked out.

Comment: Just tried this with no luck. I started from fresh: Added `should-only-show-in-master.md` then committed, created empty `dev` branch, added `should-only-show-in-dev.md` then committed, added `.gitignore` to the `master` branch, put `should-be-ignored.md` in the `.gitignore`  file then I added the `should-be-ignored.md` file the the `master` branch then committed. I `git checkout dev` and the `should-be-ignored.md` is still there, any ideas?

Comment: You're right, `should-be-ignored.md` should also be added freshly to the repo and then `gitignor`ed?

Comment: @gravetii, no, `.gitignore` only prevents files from being tracked. Listing a tracked file in `.gitignore` has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @Tom You should also delete the added file in the previous branch. Say you added `should-only-show-in-master.md` in `master` you need to delete it from your repo before checking out `dev` and making changes to it.